# Coloring different parts of a letter or number with different colors

Tags: javascript, html, css

My goal is to achieve the following image. However, I am unsure how to achieve the coloration of the numbers. As you can see, part of the number has two different colors associated to it.
[image]

There is also a similar effect on this website https://nolook.co.jp/

How can I go about achieving this look? It appears to be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `background-clip` and a gradient but backgrounds dispatched within 2 containers:

example

```css
span.difColor {
  background:linear-gradient(120deg, #F9F4E1 45%, #0F344C 45.5%);
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:400px;
}
.difColor b {background:  linear-gradient(120deg, #5A95BC 45%,#F9F4E1 45.5% );
 -webkit-background-clip:  text ;
  color:transparent;

}
```

```html
<span class="difColor"><b>20</b></span>
```

Comment: Nice solution but just to note that for some browsers (e.g. Chrome/Edge) you need also to include -webkit-background-clip: text; at the moment,

Comment: @AHaworth , oki , thought it might not be the case anymore. somethings last sometimes ;) Nice of you to point it out.